# Mysql query to get current date from database?

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone please suggest the query to get current date from data base ?

Comment: `SELECT 'www.google.com' AS answer`

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_now.asp

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[The fine manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) has this to say about the `NOW` function:

```
mysql> SELECT NOW();
        -> '2007-12-15 23:50:26'
```

If you want just the date, then use `CURDATE`. [The fine manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) has this to say about the `CURDATE` function:

```
mysql> SELECT CURDATE();
        -> '2008-06-13'
```

Answer (score 8):

MySQL Date Functions
The following table lists the most important built-in date functions in MySQL:

```
Function       Description
NOW()      Returns the current date and time
CURDATE()      Returns the current date
CURTIME()      Returns the current time
DATE()     Extracts the date part of a date or date/time expression
EXTRACT()      Returns a single part of a date/time
DATE_ADD()     Adds a specified time interval to a date
DATE_SUB()     Subtracts a specified time interval from a date
DATEDIFF()     Returns the number of days between two dates
DATE_FORMAT()  Displays date/time data in different formats
```

may be use full

SQL Date Data Types
MySQL comes with the following data types for storing a date or a date/time value in the database:

```
DATE -       format YYYY-MM-DD
DATETIME -   format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
TIMESTAMP -  format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
YEAR -       format YYYY or YY
```

Example Query :

```
SELECT NOW();
        Will Return '2007-12-15 23:50:26'
```